# Resource Not Found exception on below Lolliopop Devices

Tags: android, android-layout

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/myimage"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

On Lollipop and Marshmallow devices Image is loading.

I am Using Android  Studio and Material Design Theme

As suggested by some posts Cleaned the project,Lower size image is also added

still no luck

Comment: image is a .png file?

Comment: yes Its a .png image

Comment: Please show the full logcat output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
It got resolved after adding drawable folder and copying all images to drawable folder.
Whatever images I copied to drawable folder was added to drawable-v21 folder(it is shown as myImage(V21 inside drawable folder)).
So for pre Lollipop devices there is no image hence it was crashing.
```